# Como alterar o grid?

Tags: html, css

Olá, estou tendo problemas em colocar a parte responsiva do site, em alterar a grid de coluna para linha, já olhei bastante documentação na internet, mas ainda estou tendo bastante dificuldade em arrumar. A coluna não quebra pra linha abaixo, ultrapassando a tela, cortando parte do conteúdo.

```
.item-1{
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    width: 700px;
    grid-area: 1 / span 2 / span 3;
}
.container{
    display: grid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px){
    .item-1{
        grid-row: 1 / 2 / 3;
    }
    .item-2 input{
        width: 300px;
    }
    .item-1, .item-2, .item-3{
        width: 375px;
    }
}
```

Tentei adicionar somente as partes em que citei a grid. Não sei se ajuda, mas vou colocar o git disponível caso seja mais fácil a visualização.
https://github.com/yuriaguiar-86/join

Answer (score -1):

Basta fazer uma pequena alteração no seu código, pois você apenas não definiu o grid-row no segundo e no terceiro elemento.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px){
    .item-1{
        grid-row: 1;
    }

    .item-2 input{
        grid-row:2;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .item-3{
        grid-row: 3;
    }
    .item-1, .item-2, .item-3{
        width: 375px;
    }
}
```